# Rails + Devise - undefined method `app_user_confirmation_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I  have an app with Devise. I added :confirmable (with the corresponding migration) to my app_user_model. Now when I try to register I get an error on resource.save! in RegistrationsController

> line #5 raised: app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb 
>   undefined method `app_user_confirmation_url' for
>   ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy

Line #5 in confirmation_instructions.html.erb:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

I thought the problem is in my routes.rb so I tried adding :confirmation to them. Did not help

```
  devise_for :app_users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "app_users/omniauth_callbacks", 
                                                  :registrations => 'app_users/registrations',
                                              :passwords => 'app_users/passwords',
                                              :sessions => 'app_users/sessions',:confirmations => 'app_users/confirmations'}
```

What can I do?

**EDIT**

Rake routes:

```
           app_user_session POST     /app_users/sign_in(.:format)               app_users/sessions#create
    destroy_app_user_session DELETE   /app_users/sign_out(.:format)              app_users/sessions#destroy
 app_user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /app_users/auth/:provider(.:format)        app_users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook|twitter|google_oauth2|github/}
  app_user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /app_users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) app_users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook|twitter|google_oauth2|github)
           app_user_password POST     /app_users/password(.:format)              app_users/passwords#create
       new_app_user_password GET      /app_users/password/new(.:format)          app_users/passwords#new
      edit_app_user_password GET      /app_users/password/edit(.:format)         app_users/passwords#edit
                               PUT      /app_users/password(.:format)              app_users/passwords#update
cancel_app_user_registration GET      /app_users/cancel(.:format)                app_users/registrations#cancel
       app_user_registration POST     /app_users(.:format)                       app_users/registrations#create
   new_app_user_registration GET      /app_users/sign_up(.:format)               app_users/registrations#new
  edit_app_user_registration GET      /app_users/edit(.:format)                  app_users/registrations#edit
                               PUT      /app_users(.:format)                       app_users/registrations#update
                               DELETE   /app_users(.:format)                       app_users/registrations#destroy
       app_user_confirmation POST     /app_users/confirmation(.:format)          confirmations#create
   new_app_user_confirmation GET      /app_users/confirmation/new(.:format)      confirmations#new
                               GET      /app_users/confirmation(.:format)          confirmations#show
                               GET      /users/auth/:provider(.:format)              app_users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru
         complete_registration POST     /complete_registration(.:format)             app_users/registrations#complete_registration
        new_app_user_session GET      /login(.:format)                             app_users/sessions#new
            app_user_session POST     /login(.:format)                             app_users/sessions#create
    destroy_app_user_session GET      /logout(.:format)                            app_users/sessions#destroy
```

Registrations controller:

```
def create
  build_resource(params[:app_user])

  if resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.active_for_authentication?
      set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up 
      sign_up(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    else
      set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" 
      expire_data_after_sign_in!
      respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    end
  else
    clean_up_passwords resource

    redirect_to '/enter'
    flash[:notice] = (flash[:notice].to_a.concat resource.errors.full_messages).join("\n")

  end
end
```

Comment: Please post the relevant action in your `RegistrationsController`. Also, always worth asking...did you restart your server after running the migration?

Comment: what is in your `rake routes`?

Comment: yes I did restart the server, posted updates

Comment: For what purposes you changed Devise::RegistrationsController ?

Comment: And didn't you forget added :confirmable to model? Or maybe you  deleted this by mistake?

Comment: I did add :confirmable, I have 2 user models (admin and regular users) and I customized some stuff in registrations for omniauth.

Comment: The error is actually in Mailer/confirmation_instructions

Comment: @Stpn did you solve the problem?